# How to create multilingual Unicode text attributes in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, rdbms

I have a database and the requirement is to store the data in the columns that can:

1. hold fixed-length Unicode characters like Japanese, Chinese, French, Arabic and so on characters.
2. The data stored in a column is Unicode or multilingual and is of variable length.

In my suggestions, the Data Types are NCHAR, NVARCHAR, CHAR and VARCHAR etc...
But please tell me how what are the SQL queries to create these columns with the above-mentioned constraints.

The user requirements are to speed up the data retreival process. Also if to save hard disk.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your DBMS, you can create your database defining what would be the character encoding (normally, UTF-8 would do). Once the database was create with that encoding, you can insert text in any language. Take into account that the actual number of characters that you will be able to store within a table column will normally be less that what you defined as string length. For instance, if you create the column as `varchar(1000)`, you will NOT be able to store 1000 character in all cases.

Check your specific DBMS documentation on how to configure UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Dear @ZeshanSajid, the question includes this: **"... But please tell me how what are the SQL queries to create these columns..."**, so it is NOT only about queries. Either you didn't read/understand the question and/or my answer or the author meant something that is not reflected by his/her phrasing.